# How do you push an object into another object when the data within it gets changed?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a very large array of objects containing various errors logs. There are 1015 objects in total. At the moment I am saving the entire array every time I make a small change to a value in one of the objects. This leads to timeout errors because it takes too long to go through the whole array.

So instead I would like to figure out how I can change it so that the program ONLY saves an object if that object has been changed on the frontend.

So if I have 1015 objects and I only change something in object no. 2, then only object no. 2 should be saved on submit.

I was thinking, maybe it would be possible to first let the program look for any changes. Then IF a change has occured it will move that particular object to a new (empty) object, which I can then submit.

So, in my code example, I would like to have this function implemented on the computed property "Fields" which has the key "done". This contains a checkbox that sets the value error.done to true or false. So I would like for the program to check if this specific value has changed. If it has changed from true to false or vice versa I would like to send this object to a new object.

eg. if errors.done is set from true to false, then move the changed object to a new object called changedValue.

```
<template>
  <b-container>
    <b-card class="mt-4">
      <h5>{{ $t('events') }}</h5>
      <b-table
        :items="errors"
        :fields="fields"
        :per-page="[10, 25, 50]"
        selectable
        :select-mode="'single'"
        @row-selected="onRowSelected"
        @row-clicked="showModal"
        sort-desc
      />
    </b-card>
    <error-log-entry-modal ref="errorLogEntryModal" :selected-error-log="selectedRows"/>
    <button @click="submit">Submit</button>

  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
  import {errorService} from '@/services/error';
  import ErrorLogEntryModal from '@/components/error-log/ErrorLogEntryModal';
  import moment from 'moment';

  export default {
    components: {
      ErrorLogEntryModal,
    },
    props: {
      ownerId: String
    },
    data() {
      return {
        errors: null,
        selectedRows: []


      };
    },
    computed: {
      fields() {
        return [
          {
            key: 'done',
            label: '',
            thStyle: 'width: 1%',
            template: {
              type: 'checkbox',
              includeCheckAllCheckbox: true,
            }
          },
          {
            key: 'priority',
            label: this.$t('errorLogs.priority'),
            sortable: true,
          },
          {
            key: 'creationDateTime',
            label: this.$t('creationDateTime'),
            formatter: date => moment(date).locale(this.$i18n.locale).format('L'),
            sortable: true,
          },
          {
            key: 'stackTraceShort',
            label: this.$t('errorLogs.stackTrace'),
            sortable: true,
          },
          {
            key: 'errorMessage',
            label: this.$t('message'),
            sortable: true
          },
        ]
      },
    },
    methods: {
      load(){
          errorService.getErrorLogs().then(result => {
            result.data.forEach(log => log.stackTraceShort = log.stackTrace.substring(0,30));
            this.errors = result.data

          })
      },
      submit(){
        return errorService.setStatusOnErrorEntryLog(this.errors).then( result => {
          console.log(result)
        })

      },
      onRowSelected(fields){
        this.selectedRows = fields
      },
      showModal(){
        if (this.selectedRows) {
          this.$refs.errorLogEntryModal.show()
        }
      },
    },
    created() {
      this.load()
    },

  };
</script>
```

Comment: How are you planning to modify `errors.done`? If you are going to set `errors.done` on any action then that time you can pass the current object as a param and assign it to any other object.

Comment: Neha Soni - errors.done is a boolean, so I am just going to modify it to be either two or false.

Comment: I mean, how would you modify `errors.done`? By clicking on any element, i.e button, icon? If yes, then reread the above comment.

Comment: My apologies. I think I get your question. The errors.done object get's modified by an input (checkbox), which is a built-in the feature in the table I use on the frontend (which is why it says type: 'checkbox' in the computed property). Each row in my bootstrap table has a checkbox. If the checkbox is checked (True), then errors.done gets set to True as well for that single row.

Comment: The problem is that my submit() goes through ALL objects in Errors, while what I want to do is to check if the value errors.done has been modified in any of my thousand objects by the checkbox, and if so, only THAT object should be saved when I run the submit method. I basically want to avoid the method checking every single object if only one object has been changed. That is why my idea was to pass the object that has been modified to a new object which could THEN be run in the submit method.

Comment: Can't you trigger any event on any checkbox's click, like `onclick="submit(obj.error.done)"`. Or do you have another use case?

Comment: My meaning is, on every checkbox's click, you can pass that object and save it into any array. Then at last, when you hit submit, only use that array because that array has only modified objects inside it. Let me know If I am not clear.

Comment: Problem is that the checkbox is a third party element, which gets brought in when I add "type: 'checkbox'," in the computed template properties. I can't do much with it. That is why I was hoping it was possible to create a method that could look for changes on the objects and then send those objects to a new array.

Comment: Even if it is a third-party element, it must provide some event to trigger. Otherwise, the only way I can think about it is to use loadash library methods to compare two arrays and extract the modified objects.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly the selected rows correspond to errors.done ? In this case you can just edit the onRowSelected method like this :

```
onRowSelected(fields){
  this.selectedRows.push(fields)
},
```

Then replace this.errors by this.selectedRows in you're submit method ?